# How to erase the whole line in a CSV file and move the details to the bottom?

Tags: python, csv, logging

I am doing a login system for a quiz. If the user is already registered but not taken a quiz he should be able to log in and start quiz even if his login details are in the middle. 
so here is the csv:[image]

and here is the code

```
`def login():
    found = 0
    signed = 0
    while found != True:
        username = input("Please enter your username: ")
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        file=open("Data.csv","r")
        for line in file:
            details=line.split(",")
            if details[0] == username and details[1] == password:
                if details[4] == ('Teacher'):
                    signed = 2 #teacher log in
                    print('Teaacher login')
                else:
                    if not details[11]: #row 11 is total score
                        signed = 1 #quiz not taken
                    else:
                        signed = 3 #quiz taken
                found = True
        if found == False:
            print("Incorrect login details entered")
    if signed == 3:
        print('You have already taken a quiz')
        quit()
    if signed == 1:
        #move all the details to the last line
    return signed
```

login()`

when I log in as Gre17 with password qwerty, the code should move his details.

[image: moved]
and then start the quiz(Don't worry about that).
[image: quiz taken]
How do I make those details be moved?

Comment: Do not use `str.split()` to parse CSV - CSV is more complicated than that. Use the `csv` module.

Comment: *"the code should move his details"* - Why? What problem does it solve to move line around in the CSV?

Comment: well if there is a way to add his scores without moving them to the bottom, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better you use a database like mysql or postgre for this.But if you want to do it using csv I think you can first read the file and store the details in a list list=file.readlines().Update the required list values and write the list into the file.